# Convolution of $\mathbb{1}_{\mathbb{Q}}$

Tags: convolution

Is it possible to compute the convolution of $\mathbb{1}_{\mathbb{Q}}$ with $e^{-1/(1-t)^2}$?

Comment: Since $1_\mathbb{Q}(x) = 0$ for ae. $x$ [$m$], the answer is yes, and the value is zero.

Comment: @copper.hat do the singularities of the other function in the convolution make a difference? Certainly, $\mathbb{1_Q}*\delta \neq 0$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: The other function is very well behaved. (It can be taken to be 0 for $t=1$ which makes it continuous, but this in unnecessary.

Comment: @copper.hat ah, indeed, I forgot about the minus sign in the numerator.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: However, if it the minus sign was absent, the product is still zero ae. so the integral is still defined and zero.